# Revit pipe to GIS automated junction connection using FME

Tags: polygon, fme-form, bim

I have a revit model of pipes network having fittings and valves and network. I can export the pipes using FME workbench as 3D polylines and junctions as 3D points.

How can I snap polyline edges to the network junctions fittings manholes and valves automatically using FME?